# jquery event for mousehold

Tags: javascript, jquery

i create javascript/jquery program, it moves the sprite image when mouse is move over parent div with using mousemove event.
 my question is hot it also work continues mousedown & also work in mobile.
code is here

```
    <html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$( '.rotate' ).on( 'mousedown', function( e ) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    //$( "#log" ).text(x +', '+ y);
    if (x > 0)
    {
        $(".rotate img").css({"left":"0px"});
    }

    if (x > 60)
    {
        $(".rotate img").css({"left":"-450px"});
    }
    if (x > 120)
    {
        $(".rotate img").css({"left":"-900px"});
    }
    if (x > 180)
    {
        $(".rotate img").css({"left":"-1350px"});
    }
    if (x > 240)
    {
        $(".rotate img").css({"left":"-1800px"});
    }
    if (x > 300)
    {
        $(".rotate img").css({"left":"-2250px"});
    }
    if (x > 360)
    {
        $(".rotate img").css({"left":"-2700px"});
    }   
});
});
</script>
<style>
.rotate
{max-width:450px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.rotate img
{
    position: relative;
    left:-1360px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="rotate">
<img src="sprite.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: start a timer (setInterval) with mousedown, and clear it on mouseup - or look at `drag` events

Comment: @BojanPetkovski check the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use vmousedown, vmouseup and vmousemove events in combination to create the right behaviour (you need jQuery Mobile too, for the vmouse events to work.

[This is a working example :-D](http://jsfiddle.net/r8t297c3/9/), click on that and try it for yourself, that should get you far enough to do whatever you need to do.

```
function move ( e ) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    //$( "#log" ).text(x +', '+ y);
    if (x > 0)
    {
        $(".rotate img").animate({"left":-x.toString()}, 10);
    }

}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $( '.rotate' ).on( 'vmousedown', function (e) {
        //When mouse is clicked, started following mouse position (move)
        $(this).on('vmousemove', move);
        // Stop the select event from occurring (so you don't try an drag the image)
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    // Use the mouseup event to unbind the event listener and do any finishing up
    $( '.rotate' ).on( 'vmouseup', function (e) {
        $(this).unbind('vmousemove', move); 
    });

});
```

Comment: @Dinesh The comment on your question about setInterval isn't really useful. Firstly as I have, you can just use the events, but if you want an animation, you can use jQuery to animate the CSS to the position for smoother transitions. Also, in the modern day use [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) as it enables the browser to control the framerate, for smoother animation that doesn't choke the browser.

Comment: @Dinesh, have I answered your question? If you feel I have please mark my answer. Otherwise, was there something wrong? Just want to make sure.

Comment: first thanks for help, it try your code it was helpful for me . i try this on my pc, but i am facing a problem it was not working properly, image was not moving smoothly as i want,but i try this on jsfiddle then working good , but none of code working on mobile. http://jsfiddle.net/y35xswqe/

Comment: [I've updated the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8t297c3/9/), with animation, and update the answer too.